# Populating nested property in object initialization - C#

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
MyTool tool = new MyTool(new SubTool());
tool.PrintingSystem.Document.Target = 1;
tool.ShowPreview();
```

I want to know if it is possible to populate the `PrintingSystem.Document.Target` in initialization like this:

```
MyTool tool = new MyTool(new SubTool())
{
   PrintingSystem.Document.Target = 1
};
```

It does not work currently.

Comment: That doesn't work for you already?

Comment: Assuming that you already have the code in Visual Studio, why don't you press F5 and let us know.

Comment: [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Comment: @TheGeneral: I don't think that guide covers this situation - where the OP is trying to set a property of a value that's created by default. I can't see any examples of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of your original code with an object initializer is:

```
MyTool tool = new MyTool(new SubTool())
{
    PrintingSystem = { Document = { Target = 1 } }
};
```

This only calls the *getters* for `PrintingSystem` and then `Document`, then calls the *setter* for `Target` - just like your original code. This is a relatively rarely-used feature of object initializers, called *nested object initializers*. From the [ECMA C# standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm), section 12.7.11.3:

> A member initializer that specifies an expression after the equals sign is processed in the same way as an assignment (§12.18.2) to the field or property.
>
> A member initializer that specifies an object initializer after the equals sign is a ***nested object initializer***, i.e., an initialization of an embedded object. Instead of assigning a new value to the field or property, the assignments in the nested object initializer are treated as assignments to members of the field or property. Nested object initializers cannot be applied to properties with a value type, or to read-only fields with a value type.

It will only work if `PrintingSystem` and `Document` default to non-null values - otherwise you'd need to set the properties as per fubo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If a property is a object, refering to another object - you have to create a new instance of each to avoid a `NullreferenceException`

```
MyTool tool = new MyTool(new SubTool())
{
    PrintingSystem = new PrintingSystem() { Document = new Document() { Target = 1 } }
};
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/1G39Zs

Comment: That's assuming the constructor doesn't already initialize it. If the OP's original code works, they don't need to do this - and may not be *able* to, e.g. if PrintingSystem is a read-only property.

Comment: right but OP didn't mention it in his question so we have to assume

Comment: We've clearly understood the question differently then. I read it as "here's code that does it in two statements, but works - how can I do it with an object initializer instead?" If the OP hadn't included their existing code, or had said it throws an exception, that would be a different matter.